# linux wi-fi drivers -- structure

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I have a question related to wi-fi driver of my Laptop. How is an linux Wi-fi driver is written.

Does it have the same structure asLinux network device driver. Where Network device driver interact with socket layer using
hard_txmit() function & data is send to the network adaptor (PCI bus or direct onchip ethernet module). And on data receive an
interrupt will occur & it will push the sk_buff to the socket layer .

Is it the same way wi-fi drivers are developed on Linux platform?

found some .. its the same one ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers  ..but it uses struct ieee80211_ops ... tutorial -- http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation

also :--
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/cfg80211 
http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/

Comment: Why don't you go have a look at the code for one of the drivers?

Comment: Yes i have to look into it... but before that i just want to know from some one who have done this before ? Please suggest some wi-fi driver link ?

Comment: Just look at the existing drivers in the kernel source tree.

Comment: found some .. its the same one ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers..but it uses struct ieee80211_ops ... tutorial -- http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation

Comment: In fairness (Mat), it is pretty complicated and under-documented.  I've spent a fair bit of time hacking on madwifi, ath5k, and mac80211, and that whole space is much less clear than the wired NIC driver side.